# How to prove that a positive stochastic matrix has the maximal eigenvalue to be 1 from Perron-Frobenius?

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

There are a bunch of elementary proofs for this statement on this site and on [some others](https://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/eigenvalue-stochasti/#:%7E:text=Theorem%3A%20The%20largest%20eigenvalue%20of,x%20such%20that%20Ax%20%3D%20%CE%BBx.).

My question is, how do we go from the definition of Perron-Frobenius on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Statement_of_the_Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem), to claiming that the largest eigenvalue is 1 for a positive stochastic matrix?

Comment: using criterion 11 in the wikipedia link, with $r$ equal to the Perron root, $1\leq r \leq 1$ because the stochastic matrix has row sums of 1